# Text over the top of a border-image: Using the border as an expandable background

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an expandable background image for some text. The border-image property gives me almost exactly what I want. The problem is I don't really want a border, more that the border becomes the background for the content (specifically I like the fixed resolution edges and stretching centre). Setting height to zero gives the exact background I want, unfortunately the text is dropped below the centre:

```
height: 0px;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 100pt;
border: 149px;
border-image: url('img.png') 149 149 stretch;
```

*EDIT: for firefox* `border: solid 149px;`

http://jsfiddle.net/RL798/

1. What's the simplest way to shift the text back up?
2. Is there a simple way to add a negative offset to the width to bring the border sides in?

This is a great example where I believe negative padding would provide a perfect solution.

I'm aware there's many other ways to achieve the same result (eg a standard background image and two elements either side), but I'm after something small and simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use line-height:

http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/RL798/4/

```
div {
    height: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 100pt;
    border: 149px;
    border-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bb/Button_Icon_GreenBlue.svg/300px-Button_Icon_GreenBlue.svg.png') 149 149 stretch;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: nice! do you know how I could reduce the content width or bring in the border sides somehow?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: the border to the left and right of the text is too wide. Ideally I'd like to be able to position the text so that it almost fills the entire background. Currently the left/right borders start at the edge of the text and I'd like the text to be able to overlap the horizontal borders (as it currently does with the vertical ones). I can't set width to zero this time as I want the tag to expand as more text is added.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I guess I could try placing the text in a child tag with a negative margin.